# How do I click through all the options in the dropdown in Cypress?

Tags: automation, cypress

I want to click through the countries in the dropdown and then get the number of users in each. When I click on the country in the dropdown, it displays the number of users. I think I can loop through and then get them, but not sure how to do it.
can I use for loop and use the index to click through the elements or create an array with the country names and use them to click through?

```html
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 222px; overflow: hidden;">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" aria-label="Dropdown" style="max-height: 222px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <li data-original-index="0" class="">
      <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
        <span class="text">All countries </span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    <li data-original-index="1" class="">
      <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
        <span class="text">Belgium</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    <li data-original-index="2">
      <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
        <span class="text">Sweden</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    <li data-original-index="3">
      <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
        <span class="text">Hungary</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    <li data-original-index="4">
      <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
        <span class="text">Germany</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try following way to get element collection and iterate through the wrapped jQuery elements. Please refer [Cypress Iterate over an array of DOM elements](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#DOM-Elements) for further details. I'm not sure whether you can find unique class or id above the DOM that you have provided, if exists please alter the 'div.dropdown-menu.open > ul > li> a > span.text' css selector accordingly.

When you add class name in to css selector, if the class name contains spaces "ex: class name", then replace the "space" with "." (ex: class.name). This will looks like ('div.class.name > div.dropdown-menu.open > ul > li> a > span.text')

```
cy
  .get('div.dropdown-menu.open > ul > li> a > span.text')  //This will create countries element collection
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    //<<Add here the drop down expand element click action>>
    // $el is a wrapped jQuery element, wrap this element so we can use cypress commands on it
    cy.wrap($el).click()
  })
```